How to perform model inference with delayed inputs while ensuring real-time performance?
I need to perform model inference using a deep learning model on a stream of data. However, the challenge I’m facing is that the inputs to the model might not arrive continuously, but rather with some delay between them. Despite this delay, I need to ensure that the inference is still done in real-time.
Specifically, I want to:

Handle scenarios where the inputs are delayed by a small amount (e.g. seconds between inputs).
Ensure that the model inference is still done efficiently and in real-time, i.e., the system should respond quickly to the inputs and provide predictions in a timely manner.

I experimented with inference both with and without latency. The result shows that when performing continuous inference, the prediction time for each image is faster. I used rtmdet from Openmmlab. Below are my code and results.

Case 1: with delay

import os
import time
import cv2
from mmdet.apis import inference_detector, init_detector
import supervision as sv

config_file = r'V:\manh\train_rtmdet\work_dirs\custom\custom.py'
checkpoint_file = r'V:\manh\train_rtmdet\work_dirs\custom\best_coco_bbox_mAP_epoch_90.pth'
model = init_detector(config_file, checkpoint_file, device='cuda:0')
image_dir = r'V:\deploy\100_Image_AI'  
image_paths = [os.path.join(image_dir, f) for f in os.listdir(image_dir) if f.endswith(('.bmp', '.png', '.jpeg'))]

start_time = time.time()

for image_path in image_paths:
    time.sleep(3)
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)  
    image_start_time = time.time()  
    result = inference_detector(model, image)  
    detections = sv.Detections.from_mmdetection(result) 
    detections = detections[detections.confidence > 0.1].with_nms()  
    image_end_time = time.time()  
    image_processing_time = image_end_time - image_start_time
    
    print(f'Processing time for {os.path.basename(image_path)}: {image_processing_time:.2f} seconds')


Result:
Result of case 1

Case 2: Without delay

import os
import time
import cv2
from mmdet.apis import inference_detector, init_detector
import supervision as sv

config_file = r'V:\manh\train_rtmdet\work_dirs\custom\custom.py'
checkpoint_file = r'V:\manh\train_rtmdet\work_dirs\custom\best_coco_bbox_mAP_epoch_90.pth'
model = init_detector(config_file, checkpoint_file, device='cuda:0')
image_dir = r'V:\deploy\100_Image_AI'  
image_paths = [os.path.join(image_dir, f) for f in os.listdir(image_dir) if f.endswith(('.bmp', '.png', '.jpeg'))]

start_time = time.time()

for image_path in image_paths:
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)  
    image_start_time = time.time()  
    result = inference_detector(model, image)  
    detections = sv.Detections.from_mmdetection(result) 
    detections = detections[detections.confidence > 0.1].with_nms()  
    image_end_time = time.time()  
    image_processing_time = image_end_time - image_start_time
    
    print(f'Processing time for {os.path.basename(image_path)}: {image_processing_time:.2f} seconds')


Result:
Result of case 2
Questions:

How can I optimize the inference time when the inputs are delayed but the system should respond immediately?
Are there any specific techniques or patterns that could help in this case?

